# Beautifulsoup output with indentation

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.7

New to Python webscraping and BeautifulSoup.

I'd like to format the following so when it outputs the tags, it does so indented

```
H1 text
   H2 text
      H3 text
   H2 text
   ...
```

etc.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all(['h1', 'h2'])
for soups in tags:
print(soups.string)
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: soups.prettify()

Comment: Sadly this did not help. 
I'm not sure how to use the 'soups.prettify()

If I don't use soups.string - but soups.prettify() I get the html code, not just the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a dictionary of indents/prefixes

```
preString =  {'h1': '', 'h2': '\t', 'h3':'\t\t', 'h4':'\t\t\t'}
```

then you can just loop and print like:

```
tags = soup.find_all([t for t in preString])
for soups in [t for t in tags if t.string]:
    print(preString[soups.name]+soups.string)
```

I filtered with `if t.string` in case they have tags inside rather than just text. Using `.text` gets you the full text regardless of child tags; if you want that, and you want your `find_all` to be independent, you can instead:

```
tags = soup.find_all(['h1', 'h2'])
for soups in tags:
    preStr = preString[soups.name] if soups.name in preString else ''
    print(preStr+soups.string)
```

(You can add a default indent/prefix after the `else` when defining `preStr`)